# Positioning multiple windows with devilspie2

Tags: linux, devilspie

I often have 2 Firefox windows open  together, and I like them in opposite corners of my screen.
There’s the relevant part of my devilspie2 config file

```
--if string.match(get_window_name(), "Mozilla Firefox")
if get_application_name() == "Firefox"
then
    -- Apply default immediately
    set_window_geometry(1040,32,878, 950);

    -- Second window
    --os.execute("sleep " .. 10);
    if string.match(get_window_name(), "MySite")
    then
        set_window_geometry(0, 374, 824, 666);
    end
end
```

But the second window always has the default position.

My observations suggest that devilspie2 finishes processing the window BEFORE Firefox has loaded the site and adjusted the window title. The sleep was added in response to this, but it makes no difference, I have tried without a sleep, and with sleep times of one and ten seconds, without success. I am not a lua programmer and I got the os.execute() hint from a web search. Similarly, it makes no difference if I use get_window_name() or get_application_name() at the start.

This question might be related, but it has received no answers.
[Devilspie2 only detects Firefox windows on a restart; how can I fix this?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290593).

Does anyone know how to make devilspie2 react to a changing window title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @meuh's answer. I looked at xdotool and came up with this script, which seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox_cmd="firefox ..."
$firefox_cmd &
pid=$!
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --pid $pid \
  windowactivate \
  windowmove 0 270 windowsize 870 900
```

Comment: If you don't need the `wid` for anything else, you can "leave it on the
stack", and so use a single command: `xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --pid $pid windowmove 0 270 windowsize 870 900`

Comment: @meuh Thanks, I thought that should be possible. However, I found I also needed a `windowactivate` command. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, `devilspie2` only runs lua code on events (from `libwnck`)
due to window create, window destroy, or change of focused active window.

Using a sleep within lua will not help because changes to a window property
such as the window name will indeed cause events to be added to the queue,
but the queue will not be processed until lua returns control to
devilspie2's main loop. At that point, libwnck will update the information,
but lua will not be called again by devilspie2 until a new create, destroy,
or focus event.

One possibility is to get the window name using the standard X11 utility,
[xprop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xprop). Instead of `os.execute("sleep " .. 10);` use something like

```lua
local id = get_window_xid
local cmd = "xprop -id " .. id .. " WM_NAME"
local file = io.popen("sleep 10; " .. cmd)
local windowname = file:read("*a")
file:close()
```

I'm not a lua expert, and I haven't tested the above. The `xprop` command
is given the decimal window id of the current window, and asked for the
property WM_NAME, which it outputs in the form

```
WM_NAME(STRING) = "MySite"
```

You should then be able to use

```
string.match(windowname, "MySite")
```

It would be useful to replace the single sleep/xprop with a limited loop of shorter sleeps/xprop so that the match can be found as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I struggled to get anything useful out of xprop, but you did inspire me to think of alternative approaches. Please see my answer.